# Accessing docker from host answers curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: php, apache, docker, curl, lumen

Hi I created a centOS container and I installed (php, apache, composer and lumen).

When I run:
    php -S localhost:8000 -t public

Out put seems correct:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
PHP 7.0.27 Development Server started at Tue Jan 23 04:33:55 2018
Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is /home/blog/public
Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

I run the container like this to be able to run the server inside it:

```
docker run -it -p 8899:8000 shizus/centos:blog /usr/bin/sh
```

But on the host, when I do

```
curl localhost:8899
```

It returns

```
curl localhost:8899
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I tried with the container ip also and port 8000 also tried with 127.0.01:8899

I also tried to run the container with the server start command

```
docker run -p 8899:8000 shizus/centos:blog php -S localhost:8000 -t /home/blog/public
```

y also in detach mode

```
docker run -d -p 8899:8000 shizus/centos:blog php -S localhost:8000 -t /home/blog/public
```

This is what I get from `docker inspect`

```
[
    {
        "Id": "a136be80b2ba2b43d627c376b3e8286555a473e67b10175f9be772310b331e4b",
        "Created": "2018-01-23T15:54:04.812672134Z",
        "Path": "php",
        "Args": [
            "-S",
            "localhost:8000",
            "-t",
            "/home/blog/public"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 16953,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2018-01-23T15:54:05.180502274Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:ce9229626683d17176d2f8e5f99e948bec16b4627cd268250c1e03d5aa449833",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a136be80b2ba2b43d627c376b3e8286555a473e67b10175f9be772310b331e4b/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a136be80b2ba2b43d627c376b3e8286555a473e67b10175f9be772310b331e4b/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a136be80b2ba2b43d627c376b3e8286555a473e67b10175f9be772310b331e4b/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a136be80b2ba2b43d627c376b3e8286555a473e67b10175f9be772310b331e4b/a136be80b2ba2b43d627c376b3e8286555a473e67b10175f9be772310b331e4b-json.log",
        "Name": "/wizardly_newton",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8899"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "aufs"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "a136be80b2ba",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8000/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "php",
                "-S",
                "localhost:8000",
                "-t",
                "/home/blog/public"
            ],
            "Image": "shizus/centos:blog",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "build-date": "20180107",
                "license": "GPLv2",
                "name": "CentOS Base Image",
                "vendor": "CentOS"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "135e35cf77438a9bcfb9b5519d3fa59e9d15bc506dee164c8c61371e97271c53",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8899"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/135e35cf7743",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "9f6f68e3b3198981cb5c747dbfd3a0d689784749acc5bc9379d8adac73dc56f6",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "0d87bf18821547b37d82e877c5503d2a139d631b05fcc10fc6f99a4cd4209db9",
                    "EndpointID": "9f6f68e3b3198981cb5c747dbfd3a0d689784749acc5bc9379d8adac73dc56f6",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

When I try

```
curl localhost:8899
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

if I try

```
curl 172.17.0.2:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 8000: Connection refused
```

what do you think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the command `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000` you are binding the PHP process to the loopback interface of your docker container only (which is not the same as your host's). When you try to connect from the outside network (from your host) it won't work. You need to bind to all network interfaces.

Try with:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t public
```

This way your php process will be listening on all network interfaces inside your container and you should be able to reach it from your host

Comment: Yes! As soon as I read your answer I knew it made total sense! thank you!